# Why do I get an error when connecting to port 80 between guests

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have two VMs. Both on the nat (vmnet8) adapter. Both machines appear to be on the same subnet.

- Guest1 - 192.168.18.146
- Guest2 - 192.168.18.150

I can ssh between the machines. However, when I try http it fails:

```
[root@localhost conf]# wget 192.168.18.146
--2016-02-18 09:53:03--  http://192.168.18.146/
Connecting to 192.168.18.146:80... failed: No route to host.
```

How can I access a webserver hosted on guest1 from guest2?

I have also tried a custom adapter and bridged with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

OS firewall issue. I originally verified that iptables was not running but another service, firewalld was running and blocking access to port 80. Disabling the firewall allows me to access port 80 from my guests and host.